# Is it possible to find all date calculations in a project?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I'm trying to locate possible daylight savings issues in a huge system.

Is it possible to locate all date calculations using some kind of analysis tool?

By date calculations I mean operator +, operator -, operator <, operator <= etc for DateTime variables. Searching for datetime references and then searching for all uses of those variables is not a feasible way. The system is way too large.

Comment: I think Ctrl+Shift+F is going to be your friend with this one

Comment: Are you looking for use of `System.DateTime` or do you have a `CalculationLibrary`, and you want to find usages of this? `R#` can help with this type of scenario.

Comment: I'm looking for operator +, operator -, operator < etc for System.DateTime varaibles first.

Comment: @Tanner That's what I'm trying to find a way around. It's simply way too large.

Comment: @CarlR: I don't think it's a matter of choice. You just cannot rely on a static analysis tool, you have to sift through the code to find all DateTimes.

Comment: @RoyDictus I'm leaning heavily to suggesting that a change to DateTimeOffset is the only way to know what has been fixed or not.

Comment: @RoyDictus:  Why would a static analysis tool be "unreliable"? Why would it be less effective or efficient than a manual search? (PS: this is the Y2K problem in disguise. All the same solutions to finding those apply here)

Comment: The tool would not be unreliable, the results would be :-) That is, just because you used a static analysis tool and it gave you a number of results, that doesn't mean you have caught every instance of code that must be changed.

Comment: @Roy Dictus: Static analysis is either heuristic or conservative.  If conservative, it will list every possible result, and some additional ones the might not have the problem.    I'll remark that this isn't different than what you can do by hand; either "Carl" finds them all, or he misses some and has bugs.  You did not address the issue of efficiency in finding candidates.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible search +,-,* operator using ReSharper tool on specific data types.

E.g.`*(double parameter, double parameter):double` is the search criteria it uses to search * operation between double variables.

You just need to right click on * on the variable`double a = c*d;` and say find usage, ReSharper will do the rest.

But I am not sure how you are doing date manipulation using +,- etc...

Comment: "date + 1day" seems like a fine use of "add" on dates.

Comment: I am sorry for being ignorant, could you please give an elaborate example on using '+' operator on a date object. Because I am only aware of something like `DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime answer = today.AddDays(36);`

Comment: How about "day_of_month+1"? Obviously such date arithmetic needs adjustment to make sure that only valid dates are computed (what is [December] 31 plus 1?) so the add may be hiding in method, but the arithmetic is real enough.